# classnotfound exception but everything looks correct. can someone tell me if my start function is wrong?

Tags: java, fxml, classnotfoundexception

This is my start function in my main class:

```
public void start(Stage primary) {
    stage = primary;

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource("UserInterface.fxml"));
    try {
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        primary.setScene(scene);
    }catch( Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

the error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/micha/eclipse-workspace/woolard2/bin/masterfile/UserInterface.fxml

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2848)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processImport(FXMLLoader.java:2692)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processProcessingInstruction(FXMLLoader.java:2661)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2517)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at masterfile.Main.start(Main.java:42)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2899)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
... 15 more
```

When I comment out everything in the "try" everything works and compiles, yet when I try setting the load to root it breaks.

So it is finding the file successfully, yet won't load because it can't find the class, but it's in the same folder as class and everything.... can someone please help me

edit- UserInterface.fxml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.Scene?>

<Scene xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="model.UserController.java">

</Scene>
```

Comment: Is it the `fx:controller` class it cannot find, or a custom widget in the FXML?

Comment: I have a controller class that I have tried linking the fxml doc to but I'm getting the same error with it linked or unlinked. the fxml has been reset multiple times and changing it doesn't do anything it seems

Comment: The error can also be in the imports done in the FXML, given that the stacktrace of the cause is in `importClass`.

Comment: I just added the contents of the fxml to my post. how do I adjust the imports? I have not worked with fxml much.

Comment: okay since did the fx:controller in the fxml file it is now putting whatever I enter for "fx:controller" next to the classnotfound error. I tried doing @FXML in the user controller file but no avail

Comment: apparently I was trying to do "usercontroller.java" in the path. now that I remove the ".java" it is giving me a null root exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your FXML you have defined the `fx:controller` property as `model.UserController.java`. However your class is not `UserController.java`, that is the name of the source file, the classname is `UserController`. Modify your FXML to use `fx:controller="model.UserController"`.

Comment: you are correct I discovered this and fixing that gave me a null root error which I was able to work out by messing with the loader

Comment: Up you go ( @Wish Machine If the answer is correct, mark it as the answer please. )